# Linux paths are getting converted to windows paths in a soap call on docker #php

Tags: php, docker, soap, path

I have a stored csv file with all the images' paths stored in it.

When I tried to access it with SOAP call on docker, it changes the path - `mnt/.../pic.png` to `C:\mnt\...\pic.png`.

Is there any way to figure out why it's happening?

Comment: Yes, there is a way: Inspect the values at each step of the process, from reading the CSV to putting the SOAP response on the wire, and determine where in the flow the change is happening.

Comment: sadly I can't step by step debug the function __soapCall is in-built php helper function, so it has no body

Comment: There's no such thing as a "linux URL" or a "windows URL". URLs are universal and platform-independent. What you've shown us appear to be filesystem paths - these are completely different things from URLs. I've amended your question to make it clearer. Please try to use correct terminology wherever possible.

Comment: Is PHP running on a Windows box? Perhaps the Windows version automatically converts the path? There is really no such thing as a SOAP call "on docker" - Docker is a system container technology, not an operating system